# Graph Adjacency List Implementation (C)

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-list

I am attempting to create a adjacent ist representation of a graph in C using the following definitions...

```
typedef struct edge
{
    int to_vertex;
    int weight;
} Edge;

typedef struct edgeNode
{
    Edge edge;
    struct edgeNode *next;
} *EdgeNodePtr;

typedef struct edgeList
{
    EdgeNodePtr head;
} EdgeList;

typedef struct graph
{
    int V;
    EdgeList *edges;
} Graph;
```

The main function for creating and adding all values to the graph is

```
    int numEdges;
    int edgeToVertex;
    int weight;
    EdgeNodePtr new_node;
    Graph G;

    EdgeNodePtr current;
    int *inDeg;


    scanf("%d", &G.V);
    G.edges = malloc(G.V * sizeof(EdgeList));

    for (int i = 0; i < G.V; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numEdges);
        G.edges[i].head = NULL;


        for (int j = 0; j < numEdges; j++)
        {
            new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));

            scanf("%d,%d", &edgeToVertex, &weight);
            new_node->edge.to_vertex = edgeToVertex;
            new_node->edge.weight = weight;

            new_node->next = G.edges[i].head;
            new_node = G.edges[i].head;

        }
    }
```

For some reason I can't seem to figure out the graph won't create and I have tried firing this and it will add a node but the node will always be the same. Any help is appreciated

Comment: OT: Don't typedef pointers. It always leads to confusion.

Comment: Turns out its just my IDE being stupid and not recognising the edges array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks strange:

```
        new_node->next = G.edges[i].head;
        new_node = G.edges[i].head;
```

as you overwrite `new_node` with `head`.

Maybe you want to do:

```
        new_node->next = G.edges[i].head;
        G.edges[i].head = new_node;
```

to make `head` point to the new node.

Comment: Definitely helped, however still unsure if I am allocating the memory for the edges correctly. Shouldn't it form an array